# Is "too" or "also" better here, and where in the sentence should they be placed?

Tags: idiomatic-language

"What are you doing here (in a bar)? Is something wrong?"

"No. No, I’m just having a drink."

"You’ve had at least five since I got here. It looks pretty serious. **And actually I saw you here last week too.** So are you sure something's not wrong?"

Question: Is the sentence in bold natural? Or would any of the sentences below be better to use?

And actually I also saw you here last week.

And actually I saw you here last week also.

Plus I saw you here last week too.

Answer (score 1):

**And actually I saw you here last week too.**

Yes: that's natural. Or we might say **as well** instead of *too*.

**And actually I also saw you here last week.**

Not bad, but the first four words all start with vowels, which is a bit tiresome.

**And actually I saw you here last week also.**
- No. We don't normally end sentences with 'also'.

**Plus I saw you here last week too.**
- Yes, it's natural. 'Plus' used to be frowned on as a conjunction. Nowadays it isn't even deemed 'informal'.

[I speak BrE. Speakers of AmE may disagree with some of this answer.]

Answer (score -1):

We can use-

'And actually I saw you here last week **too**.'

'And actually I **also** saw you here last week.'

'And actually I saw you here last week **also**.'

'And actually I saw you here last week **as well**.'

**Too**, **also** and **as well** are adverbs having the same meaning. They mean 'in addition'.

**Too** is common in informal situations. We usually put it in end position.

**Also** is common in writing. We usually use it in *mid position* (between the subject and main verb), or after the modal verb or first auxiliary verb, or after 'be' as a main verb. We can use 'also' in end position. 'Also' can be used at the beginning of a sentence.

**As well** is commonly used in conversation. It usually comes at the end of a clause.

We do not usually use **too**, **also**, and **as well** in negative sentences.

Comment: "also" here is not natural in British English, maybe OK in American.